# Error when trying to open Sharepoint in Windows Server

Tags: sharepoint, iis, runtime-error

When I try to open Sharepoint in my Windows Server, following error appears:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".
```

Following is the error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +377678
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer() +31
   System.DirectoryServices.ChildEnumerator..ctor(DirectoryEntry container) +26
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.GetEnumerator() +25
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +471
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +65
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +729
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +298
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +289
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do the Following to get the idea about exact error :

1. Go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ of your web application for which you have error.
2. Open and Edit web.config file and set customErrors mode to Off.
3. See what is the main error.

Let us know the error.

Comment: i have edited the question with the actual error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occured when a login you are using is not having enough permission to login to the sharepoint site.

Check Permission of a user, it has the permission to login or not?

If you are able to able to access CA then you can add this user as Site Collection administrator, and access the sharepoint site.

Hope this helps